# SQL procedure support for Cloud Big Query

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-sql

We are trying to explore solutions which would allow us to create dynamic SQL's with multiple joins and complex SQL's involving parameters to run on Cloud BigQuery.

I have read online about federated queries which allow accessing Cloud SQL datasets from within Cloud Big Query, but is it possible to have this run the other way around i.e. use big query datasets within Cloud SQL so that native options of procedural SQL's can be used.

Largely, the purpose of these procedural SQL's is to perform large and complex pivots and run parameterized SQL's

Comment: To answer your question, no, you cannot read BigQuery data from Cloud SQL. At the moment, it's just one way i.e BigQuery can read from Cloud SQL.

Comment: Yes, I'd figured that out yesterday. In cases, where there is an explicit need to have a procedure like capability with loops. joins and filters - what is recommended?

Comment: Sorry, I don't quite understand your question now. Perhaps post a new question on SO?

Comment: @GrahamPolley could you post that comment as an answer?.

Answer (score 2):

To answer your question, no, you cannot read BigQuery data from Cloud SQL. At the moment, it's just one way i.e BigQuery can read from Cloud SQL.

Answer (score 1):

The ability to use [scripting](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/scripting) and [stored procedures](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-definition-language#create_procedure) is now in Beta.

So, you can send multiple statements to BigQuery in one request, to use variables, and to use control flow statements such as IF and WHILE, etc.
And, you can use procedure, which is a block of statements that can be called from other queries.

Note: it is Beta yet